# Embedding swf in an automated post to wall message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, flash

I want to add a swf object in a post to wall message with my app on facebook.
According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) it's possible.

I try to do it with the following code:

```
$caption = 'my caption';
$media = array('type'=>'flash', 
'swfsrc'=>'http://www.my_domain.com/embed_swf_in_ptw/src/banner3.swf', 
'imgsrc'=>'http://www.my_domain.com/embed_swf_in_ptw/src/90.jpg', 
'expanded_width'=>'160', 
'expanded_height'=>'120');

$privacy = array(
        'value' => 'SELF',
        //'friends' => 'SOME_FRIENDS',
        //'allow' => 'XXXXXXX,YYYYYYY'
);

$attachment = array('message' => 'my message',
'name' => 'my name',
'caption' => $caption,
'link' => 'http://www.my_link.com',
'description' => '',
'media' => json_encode($media),
'privacy' => json_encode($privacy),
);
try {
    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post',$attachment);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

}
```

But it won't work...
The privacy settings do work...
Do you know how to embed swf in the post?

Comment: take a look at the right documentation for `me/feed/` http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts, the REST API (the documentation link you provided) is deprecated and is going to be shut off in some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this code that works perfectly:

```
$attachment = array(
    'name' => 'APP NAME',
    'description' => 'DESCRIPTION',
    'link'=>'https://apps.facebook.com/NAME/',
    'picture' => 'http://www.my_domain.com/embed_swf_in_ptw/src/90.jpg',
    'source' => 'http://www.my_domain.com/embed_swf_in_ptw/src/banner3.swf',
    //'access_token' => 'ACCESS TOKEN'
);

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```